# Arduino get request results in FastAPI invalid HTTP request

Tags: arduino, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a uvicorn fastapi server that runs a file on port 8000 at address "example.com/sub/subsub" that returns either a 0 or a 1.
I also have an arduino running that tries to connect to this url and work with this binary value. I can't figure out why my code isn't working. The arduino keeps printing '0' to indicate that the client is not available, while my server keeps printing "Invalid HTTP request received". Can anyone help me as to what goes wrong here?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,y);
byte serverIP[] = {x, x, x, x};
EthernetClient client;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  delay(1000);
  int res = client.connect(serverIP,8000);
  Serial.println(res);
}
void loop(){
  if (client.connected() == true) {
    Serial.println("connected:)");
    client.println("GET /sub/subsub HTTP/1.0");
    if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.println(c);
    } else {
      Serial.println(client.available());
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed in loop: diconnecting...");
    client.stop();
    delay(1000);
    client.connect(serverIP,8000);
  }
delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: add `client.println();` after `client.println("GET /sub/subsub HTTP/1.0");`

Comment: @Juraj Hmm this prints a single 'H', any idea what that means?

Comment: you read and print only one character after the equest